# Itertools permutation with lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-itertools

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c','d']
from itertools import permutations
for p in permutations(items):
    p1=(''.join(p))
    p2=filter(lambda x: x[1]=='b',p1)
```

I want to exclude strings with b on the second index.
When I try to print the filter object

```
<filter at 0x7f8d729ba908>
for p in p2:
    print (p)

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-fbcaa516953f> in <module>()
----> 1 for p in p2:
      2     print (p)

<ipython-input-23-c6289753f791> in <lambda>(x)
      1 for p in permutations(items):
      2     p1=(''.join(p))
----> 3     p2=filter(lambda x: x[1]=='b',p1)

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Is lambda right choice for this?Why do I have string index problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `p` is *one* permutation. So `p2` is one string. If you filter it, your lambda function is being applied to each character in the string. So `x[1]` is out of range.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
strings = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(items)]
strings = filter(lambda x: x[1]!='b', strings)
```

or more simply

```
strings = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(items) if p[1]!='b']
```

(Using the condition `p[1]!='b'` to only include permutations where the second character is not `'b'`)

Answer (score 10):

`filter` is fine, but you have to apply it outside the loop. The problem with your code is that you are passing a string to `filter`, so a `str`ing is treated as an iterable and iterated upon, one character at a time. Since a character is a string of size 1, `x[1]` is guaranteed out of bounds.

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != 'b', permutations(items))) # remove list(..) if you're using python2
```

If you want a list of strings, you may apply a `map`:

```
perms = list(map(''.join, filter(lambda x: x[1] != 'b', permutations(items))))
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(items) if p[1] != 'b']
```

If you want to print it out as it is generated, use a loop instead:

```
for p in permutations(items):
    if p[1] != 'b':
        print(''.join(p))
```

Also, the `filter` condition includes items where the condition is true, so your condition needs a slight modification, if you want to exclude strings whose first character is `b` (you'd need `x[1] != b`, rather than `x[1] == b`).

Comment: notice that there is no need to consume filter calling list in `python2`

Comment: @DanielSanchez Under the assumption OP is on python2, you're right.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Why do you insist on creating a list?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hmm, no, you don't see what I mean and didn't fix it. You still insist on creating a list, now even more than before. Why? The question doesn't ask for it, and the shown use case `for p in p2: print (p)` doesn't need it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Okay. The main thing I wanted to convey in my answer was what OP was doing wrong and how to fix it. The creation of a list (or lack thereof) is secondary.